# Elasticity and Hooke's law: who is applying the force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, spring, elasticity, structural-beam

I am currently studying longitudinal vibrations in an elastic beam. However, I am struggling a bit because it is the first time I have done continuum mechanics. More specifically, when isolating an infinitesimal portion of the beam, who is applying the force on each face? Is it the infinitesimal elements next to it $[x - dx;x]$ and $[x+dx;x+2dx]$?

I understand Hookes' law as a law analogous to the law of springs, so my guess was that in order to find the force acting on the left side I have to observe the stretch of the portion $[x-dx ; dx]$ and multiply this value by the Young's modulus and the surface in order to find the force it exerts on $[x, x+dx]$. Is this the right way of looking at things?

[image: Diagram of a portion of a beam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically correct. Internal stresses in the beam will be communicated from one infinitesimal element to the next as you describe. For the purposes of longitudinal vibrations you can think of the beam as being made up of a large number of very small springs connected end to end. Young's modulus plays a similar role to the spring constant in Hooke's law. You may also have to take into account external constraints e.g. one end of the beam could be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the diagrams you have shown, we regard x as an embedded material coordinate inscribed within the beam. It identifies, for all time, the set of material points at a given cross section.  Thus, the embedded coordinate does not change when we deform the beam.  This method of labeling the material points chooses the spatial coordinate of a material point before the beam has been deformed as its constant material coordinate.

The spatial coordinate of a material point after the beam has been deformed is x + u(x), where u(x) is referred to as the displacement of the material point that was at spatial coordinate x before the deformation.  So two material points that were at x and $x+\Delta x$ before the deformation are now located at x + u(x) and $x+\Delta x +u(x+\Delta x)$.  So the distance between the two material points has increased from $\Delta x$ to $\Delta x + u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)$.  So the local strain is $$\epsilon(x)=\frac{u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{du}{dx}$$